# Access class from another C++ file

Tags: c++, oop

So I have a "main.cpp" file which I have declared an object of my class player:

main.cpp:

```
#include "player.h"

Player player;

int main() {
  //
  player.update();
}
```

I would like to access this object from multiple different C++ files. However, I would like to do this without using the keyword `extern` as i'm trying to stay away from global variables.

Hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "as i'm trying to stay away from global variables" - `player` is global. To "access from different files" you need a global variable, or to pass it around.

Comment: What does "pass it around" mean as that may help?

Comment: First of all, you don't access something from a file. You can access anything from a program, a function, a module, but not a file. Second, you can't use any object or class without first declaring it. So, if you want to access an object in another module, you must declare it as ```extern```. It is intended exactly for this purpose. If you use C++17 and above, you can put your object in a header file and declare it as ```inline```. In C++17 this does the same as declaring the object in a cpp, and use it as ```extern``` in other module

Comment: Have a local variable and pass it as a parameter to the code that needs it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than write functions like

file1.cpp

```
#include "player.h"

extern Player player;

void doStuffToPlayer() {
    player.update();
}
```

file2.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "file1.h"

Player player;

int main() {
    doStuffToPlayer();
}
```

You can instead write

file1.cpp

```
#include "player.h"

void doStuffToPlayer(Player & player) {
    player.update();
}
```

file2.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "file1.h"

int main() {
    Player player;
    doStuffToPlayer(player);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is useful but I have a question. Can I pass the object then set a variable to the passed object?

Comment: @JakeHughesMusic yes, there's only one `Player` object in this example